# Sending jpeg image to a Servlet and convert it to a BufferedImage

Tags: java, servlets

I need to send(upload) a jpeg image to a Servlet and rather than saving it on file, I want to  turn it into a BufferedImage and do some processing on it.

This is my code for the client side:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9000/upload");
File file = new File("/tmp/lena.jpg");

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);


httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
if (resEntity != null) {
    resEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

How can I receive the image in a Servlet and process it?

I tried this on my receiving side Servlet, but the image is null:

```
InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(is);
```

Finally, I should not save anything on disk in the process.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Part file = request.getPart("userfile");
InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
```

Comment: The answer is correct, however If you want to use Servlet 3.0 HttpServletRequest#getParts() method , then you must annotate your servlet with @MultipartConfig.

After that, things worked